# Changing the network interface for specific user?

Tags: networking, iptables

I have more than two users on my system and two different network interfaces and I would like to make my second user to preferre one of them.

One of these devices are eth0 and tun1. Is it possible to achieve this or are options like these systemwide?

The other user should continue using eth0.

Yes I am using ubuntu. (18.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to mark the packets with 'owner' see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104830/block-specific-application-with-iptables)). The `MARK` extension based on processes and users.

```
iptables ... -j MARK --set-mark 15
```

Once the packets have been marked, you can create the new routes, for example, a new default route, and associate it to a routing table:

```
ip route add table 10 your_route_for_that_user
```

Then you tell the system to route all packages with the mark 15 by using table 10 (15 and 10 could be any valid number for `ip route add table` and `-j MARK`):

```
ip rule add fwmark 15 table 10
```

Comment: OK. First of all thank you very much but sadly I couldnt get it to work.
The tunnel I want to use is created with openvpn, that usually creates and rerouting gateway but I turned that off to make the system use eth0.

The commands I used:
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner vpnapp -j MARK --set mark 15

$ ip route add table 11 10.8.8.0/24 via 10.8.8.5 dev tun1
and then
$ ip rule add fwmark 15 table 11

Are these correct?

Comment: It is not clear whether you are redirecting an user or an application. Anyway, the MARK-ing rule should go in PREROUTE.

Comment: I want to redirect those packets by user. Everything coming from user "xyz" should go to 10.8.8.0.. I just read that the user cant be "seen" when using prerouting. Is this even possible?

Comment: Sorry, it is in the OUTPUT chain.

Comment: Thank you for your relpy. The command worked with OUTPUT. Next problem: they dont get marked. When I run curl ifconfig.me on the xyz user I just get the default ip. Iptable output: https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/34g6

Comment: You need different routing tables and a rule to let the system decide when to use which. It might get tricky, depending on your setup. I recommend you edit the answer with the actual commands and the problem, and somebody will be able to help. Consider using the LOG target in iptables and start with something as simple as ping to be able to test. Ping is safer because curl, for example, could be going through a proxy or be rerouted for other reasons. Start simple and build the solution up. And if you ask here, please add the commands you used.